# View live updates of database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an SQLite database collecting information on my Android App users. As long as I create the database in the app itself, data input works fine and I can also display the contents of the database without a problem.

I am looking for a way to connect live to this database from an external browser (e.g. DB Browser) without having to download the most current version of the database via device file explorer.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the Database Inspector for this, which already includes live updates option? https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

Comment: @Mark - it is an app for robot Pepper, so I need the min SDK level to be set to 23.  I understand the Database Inspector requires 26 or higher.